# YouTube player takes control from my YouTube Javascript API page on Windows Phone when video started?

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, youtube-api, windows-phone

I have a web page that uses the YouTube Javascript API (iframe method) to play videos.  It works great on desktop and tablet browsers.  However, on Windows Phone whenever I start the video using the YouTube API playVideo() method, my page gets dumped and the YouTube full player takes over the screen.  Is there anyway to keep this from happening so my page can stay resident?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Windows Phone 8.0

This is the expected behaviour - when a webpage initiates video playback, the built-in video player handles playback in full-screen.

The only way to control the experience is to use the native [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207066%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and essentially create your own video player experience (eg. [MetroTube](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/metrotube/8d93224f-2808-e011-9264-00237de2db9e?signin=true))

### Windows Phone 8.1

A [new in-line video playback option has been introduced](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/05/07/what-s-new-in-internet-explorer-11-for-windows-phone.aspx) for the WebBrowser, which allows YouTube videos to be played without taking you away from the webpage.